# Correct image rotation/scale/moving change

Tags: transform, scale-space

I'm pretty new to Image Processing and am using MatLab.
I have an problem were I take an image of light passing trough an set of optical fibers (bundled together) and one were I pass laser energy trough the same bundle of fibers to burn the image of these fibers onto paper. 
I then try to match these two. Up to now I just basicly imported both into photoshop and rotated, scaled and resized by hand to match them. However I am looking for an automated method in Matlab as I'm also doing different analysis on these pictures in matlab. 
So I'm looking for an automated method to find the rotation, scale an movement difference of both images. 
I tried a lot of different things using mostly different tools from the matlab imaging processing toolbox (SURF, BRISK, FAST) without success. Also with different optimizations of the image from just the basic matlab imadjust to changing to hue scale, contrast changes, brightness, denoising. 
[image: burned image]
[image: light image]
(i have higher resolution available)
Is there anyone who can send me in the right direction?

Comment: What went wrong when you tried to use surf?

Comment: It only gave two different points which "should match" but those didn't match at all. So while correcting the image using surf it gave the completely wrong results. Any suggestions how to improve this as surf feeled like it should be able to work. I do not understand much how to fine tune surf so if there is any good guide or free online-tutorial I would be happy to read/follow that.

Comment: I would break your problem into two steps. First try and identify the location of each fiber. Then try and find a correspondence of the fibers between the two images. To do that you could guess a correspondence then check how good it is. Then repeat until you find something good.